# How to replace newlines with "\n" string in Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an Excel which I need to convert to a specific format to be written into a CSV file. One of the problems I am facing is I have cell values with newlines.

Eg:

`Hi, This is Me. 
This is a standard Description. 
This is what I do.`

I want to replace the new lines with the string "\n as shown below.
Eg:

```
Hi, This is Me.\n This is a standard Description.\n This is what I do.
```

I am not able to do so.

I have tried replacing \n with \n this does not work. However \n with empty string or any other valid character works.

```
import pandas as pd
my_sheet = 'Sheet1' # name of the sheet in the excel file
file_name = 'bulkload_format.xlsx' # name of my excel file
df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name = my_sheet)
cols = [16] # i want data in column 16 alone, this has \n characters that needs replacing
df = df[df.columns[cols]]
df = df.replace('\n','\\n', regex=True) #this does not work
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(index, row[0])
export_csv = df.to_csv('out.csv', index = None, header=True, encoding='utf-8') #it directly write new lines in the CSV
```

\n literal needs to be replaced with \n string.

Comment: Have you tried out `df.column.str.replace('\n', '\\n')`? See [explanation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html)

Comment: @Albo I am getting below error:
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'iterrows'

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A faster solution using the [text](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#working-with-text-data) capabilities of `pandas`, compared to @Rajith Thennakoon's solution would be:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace('\n', '\\n')
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 663 µs per loop
```

compared to

```
df['temp'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: x.split('\n'))
df['name'] = df['temp'].apply(lambda x: ' \\n '.join(x))
df.drop(columns=['temp'])
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.98 ms per loop
```

Comment: I can confirm this is also working as with Rajith's solution. I am going to go ahead with this solution since I have to go through a lot of data and the time complexity is something I have to keep in mind to keep things snappy.
Thank you @Albo

Answer (score 1):

This will not the most efficient solution,hope this will work,
lets take your column name as as `text` and dataframe as `df`

```
df["temp"] = df["text"].apply(lambda x: x.split('\n'))
df["text"] = df["temp"].apply(lambda x: ' \\n '.join(x))
df.drop(["temp"])
```

Comment: Perfect. This solution works for me. I had to change one line though 
`df.drop(columns=['temp'])`

Comment: great,happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is definitely not the best solution, but a very simple one.
If you have your text in the cells, `A1`, `A2`, and `A3`, you could make it with a cell in `b1` and the following formula:

`=a1&"\n"&a2&"\n"&a3&"\n"` ...